Is this star schema model valid or does it required updates to be more efficient?
I am working with a DataWarehouse from which I'll be collecting data, I am trying to build a star model schema on data modeler in order to be then use on Snowflake and then later in Power BI for BI analysis.
The Datawarehouse with all the columns that I can use is names as FinOps_DW, the other tables are following the convention with fact and dimension tables.
I have in the DW some id such as resource_id and account_id however when I build my schema I created a new id column to cover all the attributes of the tables and not only resource or account.
Is it a good practice to do so? What could be done to improve this star schema model ?
Is it allowed to avoid multiple id in a single table (outside of the fact table) ?
Does the choices of tables sounds logical to you ?
enter image description here
I've been trying to test various tables composition from the DW attributes but I lack of experience in star schema design.

Hi - 1) please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable test, appropriately formatted 2) you need to limit yourself to a single, coding-based question that doesn't need an opinion-based answer. Asking questions such as "is it efficient?" are unanswerable - efficient compared to what?

Creating a new ID for a fact table often brings cardinality issues because it allows duplicate data to be saved. Typically, the key in the fact table is composed of the combination of keys for each dimension related to the table. If you need to incorporate new data then new dimensions are added, new measures are added to the definition of the fact table and a new key is added to the combined key of the fact table.
